# WM8804 audio routing question

Tags: dsp, i2s, spdif

The WM8804 looks like the ideal candidate for a design I'm working on --- this single chip could replace the need for one receiver and one transmitter.  The specific routing requirements are:

I need one of the following two configurations, selectable "on-the-fly", during operation (say, a switch that a microcontroller reads, and the microcontroller uses GPIO pins to control and reconfigure the WM8804):

- I2S input → route to SPDIF output
- SPDIF input → route to both I2S output ***and*** SPDIF output

Table 15 on page 20 and Figure 15 on page 20 of the [WM8804 datasheet](https://statics.cirrus.com/pubs/proDatasheet/WM8804_v4.5.pdf) suggest that it can do that: TXSRC selects the source for the SPDIF transmitter;  the diagram in Figure 15 shows that the output of SPDIF RX goes to both the I2S and the SPDIF transmitter;  if I set, in hardware/standalone mode, CSB = 0  (corresponding to TXSRC = SPDIF RX), the multiplexer will select SPDIF RX as the source for SPDIF TX, but SPDIF RX will ***also*** go to the I2S decoder and ultimately DOUT.

I have had enough ugly surprises with datasheets' misinformation (or hidden information, especially about limitations of the device) that I'm paranoid enough and would like to ask:

Anyone out there has tried this or similar configurations with the WM8804 and can confirm that this is the case?

In case this makes a difference: please notice,  although I'll have a microcontroller on the same board, I *really, really* prefer to use the WM8804 in standalone/hardware mode;  even if the microcontroller will drive the few pins that the WM8804 will read at startup to determine its configuration.

Comment: You aren't really focusing on a proper EE question - I'm sure there are folk out there but you are just going to get opinions and they aren't really valid for this site.

Comment: Not sure why you expect that this question will only get opinions.  There's a specific, objective characteristic of this device that my design depends on, and I'm hoping that people that have used the chip will know the answer for sure;  I give you that I may get answers along the lines of:  "the datasheet says 'the chip does X', why would you ask us whether the chip does X or Y?" --- that's why the clarification about my recent experiences with datasheets doing a truly lousy job at making it clear what the device does or doesn't do.

Answer (score 1):

Digging some more, I found [this other electronics.SE post](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/439022/i2s-mclk-generation) that answers my question (in passing, but still explicitly). The answer being: yes, the WM8804 does as indicated in the datasheet, Figure 15.